# plotting the points x and y, the axes y and x are not shown correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to generate a line chart loading csv files by placing points on the x and y axis. for some strange reason the axes are not shown correctly. I have negative values for x and y. so it should have a Cartesian plane like the one in this image. in this case the complete Cartesian plane must be shown. In my  points there are negative values in x and y.

[image]

I do not know why the points are showing wrong.

[image]

the update button, load new points updating the values of the graph.

http://plnkr.co/edit/dDx8gRZIfjvemWpgikAp?p=preview

```
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


// Set the ranges
var x =  d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.datax); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.datay); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

The negative values in x and y is not displayed because your minimum domain value is 0:

```
x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.datax; })]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.datay; })]);
```

It should have been(so that it sets the minimum value of dataset as domains minimum)

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.datax; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.datay; }));
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Y7UnnmscgHA4oHlWrDo?p=preview)

Comment: as I said in the question, I need to have the Cartesian plane as in the image, in my code the points are shown too rare. https://i.imgur.com/klA6pZK.jpg